# How can I solve thoses errors in opencv with cuda in python during building CMake?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

I’m trying to use the OpenCV with cuda, but i can manage to build the OpenCV through CMake, but the Build processo finishes with many erros like:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(248,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item E:\OpenCV\builds\CMakeFiles\73fe723e92479b05f06abfab27cdceae\opencl_kernels_core.cpp.rule succeeded, but specified output e:\opencv\builds\modules\core\opencl_kernels_core.cpp has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
C:\OpenCV\sources\opencv-4.7.0\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp(51,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: ‘opencl_kernels_core.hpp’: No such file or directory
```

and many other with ‘opencl_kernels_*.hpp’

But also other errors like:

```
Done building project opencv_core.vcxproj – FAILED.
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file ‘…..\lib\Release\opencv_core470.lib’
```

```
Done building project opencv_hfs.vcxproj – FAILED.
Done building project opencv_img_hash.vcxproj – FAILED.
Done building project opencv_plot.vcxproj – FAILED.
Done building project opencv_quality.vcxproj – FAILED.
Done building project opencv_cudafilters.vcxproj – FAILED.
```

and it kept with many other like those.

The entire log is here: https://textdoc.co/tD6aTXLh3geqo5uk

I tried to many tutorials, between them:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8Jx6zO1yw0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NwU1MmmqWo
- https://thinkinfi.com/install-opencv-gpu-with-cuda-for-windows-10/

and variations.

- Cuda 12.2
- CUDNN
- fresh instalation of Python 3.11
- Vistual Studio 2022 (with Desktop development with C++)
- CMake 3.26.4 opencv and opencv-contrib 4.7.0 (source) release

And there are the log of CMake: https://textdoc.co/TudfOPlpIzUbGg5s

I’m running on a Windows 11 machine with 2060 Super